# How to understand level of parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Imagine i have such classes:

```
class Base
{
};

class D2: public Base
{
}

class D3: public D2
{
};

class D4: public D3
{
};
```

goes on...

And i have a list of pointer of **Base** class.

Suppose that i dont know the order of inheritance of these classes. I can only understand if a pointer is instance of a given class. (i cant check manually because people will register these classes later)

Example:

```
D3* d3 = new D3();
D2::isInstance(d3); //return true
D4::isInstance(d3); //return false
```

When i pop a pointer of **Base** class, i want to cast it into most derived class.

**Main Question:**
Is there a C++ method that i can understand if D3 is inherited from D2 or not?? if there exists such a method i can solve.

Thanks.

Comment: check this out [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

Comment: thanks Olzhas. I think this is the answer

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't need to know what derived class it is.  All Base classes need to have all methods required to use them without resorting to determining its type.  This is not best practice.

Comment: Some how i should create new classes related to type of these Base classes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not checking particular objects, you can use `std::is_base_of`, it is compile time, thus is safe. 
[link to reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: @VolAnd, you're welcome :) I believe implementation came from Andrei Alexandrescu. It's on youtube somewhere and it's really compile time, but I can't recall which conference it was.